# How to get data from interval in MongoDB?

Tags: python, mongodb

Data:

```
x   y   timestamp
123 123 1000165
123 123 1000167
123 123 1000160
123 123 1000168
123 123 1000154
123 123 1000132
123 123 1000112
```

How get data from timestamp interval [time1;time2]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
db.foo.find({
    $and: [
        {"timestamp" : { $lte: 1000112}},
        {"timestamp" : { $gte: 1000165}}
    ] 
})
```